# TYPO3 Flux Forms not working in BE as non-Admin

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a strange behavior in a Flux Provider Extension.
I registered a FLUX Content (...registerProviderExtensionKey) in ext_tables.php.
I am now able to create a new Flux Content in BE as admin. Everything is working well in BE and FE. Now I logged in BE as non-admin User and some of the FLUX Content Element Fields are missing.

[Screenshot of Admin View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVCIz.png)

[Screenshot of User View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS0mo.png)

There seems to be a permission problem with the flexform field in the tt_content.

Working with TYPO3 8.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
It i required to set the "exclude" option in FLUX!
Example:

```
<flux:form.sheet name="links" label="Link List">
            <flux:field.input exclude="0" name="title" label="Text wrapped by Link" />
            <flux:field.input exclude="0" name="link" label="Link">
                <flux:wizard.link/>
            </flux:field.input>
        </flux:form.sheet>
```